# How to check if user input is of correct data type in C

Tags: c

Am new to programming so apologies if I've done anything stupid.

I am trying to make a program in C that reads a floating-point number from the user and prints it if it is a valid float in-between the values of 0 and 20, otherwise it will ask again.

The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float a;
    do {
        do {
            printf( "Please input a number (0-20):" );
        } while ( scanf( "%f", &a ) != 1 );
    } while ( ( a < 0 ) || ( a > 20 ) );
    printf("%f\n", a );
    return 0;
}
```

If I enter a number, it works as intended. However, if I enter anything else (such as a character), it breaks and repeatedly prints out the message.

What have I done wrong? I read in another thread that I can use the return value of scanf to verify that
the input is of the intended data type but that doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: The best advise would be [*not* to use `scanf`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). The reason you are getting this is that `scanf` is not removing the bad input from the stream, so you end up with reading it over and over.

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`. All user input is a string anyway, it is just `scanf` parsing floats out of it. `scanf` will return an int, corresponding to the number of values successfully read.

Comment: It might be better not think in terms of the word "type" but rather in terms of input format. Does the supplied input have an accetable format? Where "acceptable" means can be interpreted at a floating point value. Or better can be interpreted in whole (i.e. with nothing left over) as a floating point value. Why? Because the user input is *text*.  All of it if you are working from the command line. The user doesn't type a `float` or a `int`, they type *text*. Then you processes that somehow to come up with an interpretation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read the input to a string buffer first (using `fgets`) and then convert this string buffer to the desired floating point number (using `sscanf`). This way you could also perform additional checks on the input string and give the user meaningful error messages for bad inputs.

Note that `sscanf` will be satisfied once it has filled its arguments, so it will also accept strings like '2x' (as the number 2.0).

```
int main()
{
    float a;
    char buffer[10];
    do {
        do {
            printf( "Please input a number (0-20): " );
            fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin );
        } while ( sscanf( buffer, "%f", &a ) != 1 );
    } while ( ( a < 0 ) || ( a > 20 ) );
    printf("%f\n", a );
    return 0;
}
```

For your range check, note that [floating point comparison](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) is not trivial due to the internal representation of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is structured into lines, you can use the following logic

```
   float result ;
   for ( ;; ) {      // loop forever
       printf("Please input ...\n") ;
       char buff[256] ;
       if ( fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), stdin) ) {
           if ( sscanf(buff, "%f", &result) == 1 ) {
               // additional verification on result
               if ( result >=0 && result <= 20 ) break ;
           } ;
       } ;
   } ;
   // Use Result here
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because scanf( ) does not clear the invalid input. It's better to use something like gets( ) or fgets( ) and try to convert to float by using something like atof( ).

If you must use scanf( ), clear the invalid input manually by something like this:

```
while ( ( getchar( ) ) != '\n' );
```