# How to go back to the beginning of a case if the conditions aren't met

Tags: c, switch-statement

`

```
switch(selectedOption){
  case 'B':
    printf("Please enter the first number\n");
    if (scanf("%f", &firstNumber) == 1){
       printf("Is a valid number\n");
    }
    else{
       printf("Is not a valid number\n");
    }
}
```

`

I have a school assignment where I have to program a calculator. One of the requirements is to ask for the user to input another number if they for example input a character instead of a number. I'm not sure how to go about this and I looked everywhere and no solutions made sense. I would appreciate it a ton if someone could help me out with this problem.

Comment: You put the `switch` inside a loop. If you were using `if` instead of `switch`, you'd do `break;` to exit the loop. But, `break;` inside a `case` just ends the case. So, you need an extra variable. Try: `int valid = 0; while (! valid) { switch (selectedOption) { case 'B': printf("Please enter the first number\n"); valid = (scanf("%f", &firstNumber) == 1); printf("Is %sa valid number\n",valid ? "" : "not "); break; } }`

Comment: @CraigEstey `continue` inside the `switch` would also *continue* to the next loop iteration.  But that's getting awfully complex and hard-to-maintiain.  I'd delegate the "get a number" to a function that gets a valid number from the user.

Comment: I believe this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399995/how-to-check-if-user-input-is-of-correct-data-type-in-c?rq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633005/validate-the-type-of-input-in-a-do-while-loop-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to loop until valid input has been read (assuming the input comes from an interactive agent such as a person sat at a terminal).

The following **will not work**:

```
switch(selectedOption){
  case 'B':
    while (1) {
      printf("Please enter the first number\n");
      if (scanf("%f", &firstNumber) == 1){
         printf("Is a valid number\n");
         break;
      }
      else{
         printf("Is not a valid number\n");
      }
    }
    /* ... */
    break;
}
```

The problem is that `scanf` will stop reading input when it sees a character that is not part of the number, and will push that character back onto the stream (c.f. `ungetc`).  For example, if the input is    `-foo`, `scanf` will read the spaces, then the `-` (which could be part of the number), then the `f` which is not part of the number.  The `f` will be pushed back onto the stream and `scanf` will return 0.  On the next iteration of the while loop, `scanf` will read the `f`, push it back onto the stream and return 0. Loop *ad infinitum, et ultra*.

To break the infinite loop, the code needs to read something from the stream and discard it.  One option is to read and discard the next word by calling `scanf("%*s");`, or discard the next word and the following whitespace character by calling `scanf("%*s%*c");`, or discard the remainder of the line and the newline by calling `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");`. E.g.:

```
switch(selectedOption){
  case 'B':
    while (1) {
      printf("Please enter the first number\n");
      if (scanf("%f", &firstNumber) == 1){
         printf("Is a valid number\n");
         break;
      }
      else{
         printf("Is not a valid number\n");
         scanf("%*s");
      }
    }
    /* ... */
    break;
}
```

Note that input such as `42foo` will be considered valid by the above code. `scanf` will push the `f` back onto the stream and return 1 because it has read a valid number `42`.  You may want to read the next character and check that it makes sense.  You can always push at least one character back onto the stream by calling `ungetc(ch, stdin);` so that it can be re-read later.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me  a ton. I haven't learned this at all in my class so it was pretty difficult to figure this problem out. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You do not need switch - case.
You just need to do:

```
while (true) {
    char number = 0;
    scanf_s("%c", &number);
    if (number >= '0' && number <= '9') break;
    else printf("Is not a valid number\n");
}
```

Comment: This isn't sufficient. Just testing for range `0-9` isn't enough. User could enter `1Q` and it would pass your test. What about: `if (scanf("%f",&number) == 1) break;` instead?

Comment: And the user could enter `foo` and it would go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Checking for a value between 48.00 and 57.00 (because `'0'` is 48 and `'9'` is 58) isn't all that plausible.  I'm assuming `number` is a `float`; if it isn't, there's a mismatch between the conversion specification (`"%f"`) and the argument.  You're missing a semicolon after `scanf()`.  You must check that `scanf()` worked before using `number`.

Comment: That's true. I did not compiled it. Now should do the work if he want to enter a digit at a time

Comment: `scanf_s()`?!?  That's *de facto* not portable, nor is it any "safer".  Read this: [**Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces**](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)

Comment: Yes I know. My compiler does not let me use scanf(). I personally do not use any of them.